# having trouble in passing req data in post fumction through html form in node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am newbie to nodejs. Facing problem in posting data throug html forms....
In my server.js i have added this post function request

```
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.end(`
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <body>
  <form action="/product" method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

  <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="title"> 

  <input type="number" name="price"  placeholder="price"> 
    
  <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="description"> 

  <input type="text" name="category" placeholder="category" > 

  
  <input type="file" name="product" >

  <button>Save</button>
</form> 
  </body>
  </html>
`);
})
```

Post function decleration in product.js

```
const productRouter = express.Router();
productRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

productRouter.route('/')
.get((req,res,next)=>{
    Product.find({})
    .then((products)=>{
        res.statusCode=200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        res.json(products);
    },(err)=>next(err))
    .catch((err) => next (err));
})
.post((req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    var Prod= new Product({
        title:req.body.title,
        price:req.body.price ,
          description: req.body.description,
          category:req.body.category,
          img: req.body.img
    });
    Prod.save()
    .then((product)=>{
        console.log('product added ',product );
         res.statusCode=200;
         res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
         res.json(product);
        
    },(err)=> next(err))
     .catch((err) => next(err));
})
```

**Post request in working fine when i am doing it using POSTMAN , but when try to do using html form i am facing the follwing error:**

ValidationError: Product validation failed: title: Path `title` is required., price: Path `price` is required., description: Path `description` is required., category: Path `category` is required., img: Path `img` is required.
at model.Document.invalidate (C:\Users\mayank\Desktop\cata\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2598:32)

Comment: What’s console.log(req.body) printing?

Comment: @SatyaKalluri Its just giving an empty object.... {}

Comment: posted a potential solution in the answers section. Let me know,  how it goes.

Comment: OK,  gotcha. My bad too. body-parser cannot be used straight out for multipart content. I have updated the solution that gets your job done. Check  it and let me know.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Check the notes from body-parser README section (attached screenshot for reference). BodyParser doesn't support the multipart styles due to their complexity. Instead, listed some nm-modules to use.

I suggest [MULTER](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#readme) or [MILTIPARTY](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty#readme)

Here's a reference of the code that's working.I have sent the received-payload as JSON response.  You could go ahead and process the way, you intend.

```
router.post('/ola', (req, res) => {
  var form = new multiparty.Form();
  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    res.json({ fields: fields, files: files });
  });
  
})
```

[image]

Comment: I have already used this in my code. But it's still showing that error

Comment: The above comment by @codemarvel was for an earlier solution. I have updated the answer with a tested solution. Check it  out.